# Componentes del Formulario se desconfiguran - NetBeans

Tags: java, java-swing

Al momento de correr el software en NetBeans funciona bien, pero pasado un tiempo los componentes se empiezan a desconfigurar así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fijándome bien, en realidad creo que los componentes siguen manteniendo su posición y tamaño, el problema esta cuando el mouse pasa por encima de los botones o los items del `PopupMenuItem` de la tabla, la verdad no se porque pasa esto, es como si el puntero del mouse estaría replicando el formulario activo cada vez que lo paso por encima de un botón o un item del popupmenuitem de la tabla, ayuda por favor, necesito solucionarlo porque esto es para mi proyecto de grado, no es cualquier trabajo.

**CONFIGURACIONES DE LA TARJETA GRAFICA**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna tarjeta de gráficos?¿Ya probaste a deshabilitarle el anti aliasing?

Comment: Si, tengo una portátil gamer con una tarjeta de video NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 980, are la prueba deshabilitando el anti aliasing.

Comment: nos cuentas que tal te va, si no para darte más sugerencias

Comment: Te cuento que ya estaban deshabilitados, agregue unas capturas de la configuración de mi tarjeta grafica.

Comment: Ya intentaste ponerle el look and feel del sistema?

Comment: Hola, te cuento que sigue igual, puse en el método principal este código `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");` pero no se soluciono el error.

Comment: Si usas Java 8 intenta agregar esta opción al correr tu jar: `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false`

Comment: Si funciona, pero hay un problema, solo funciona cuando lo hago correr desde el IDE NetBeans, pero cuando le doy a `Limpiar y Generar Project` y lo hago correr desde el ejecutable JAR generado no funciona.

Comment: y con la opción `-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true`?

Comment: Pasa lo mismo, los códigos que me estas dando los estoy poniendo en NombreDeMiProyecto->Propiedades->Ejecutar->Opciones de la máquina virtual. ¿Es correcto o tenia que ponerlos en otro lado?

Comment: al correr tu jar desde consola

Comment: Acabo de hacer la prueba y funciona desde consola, pero no puedo decirle al cliente que cada vez que quiera usar el software tenga que hacerlo desde consola, no hay alguna forma de poner esos parámetros directamente cuando se ejecute desde el JAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir del cambio de [java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7) a [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) algunos problemas gráficos se presentaron con la librería swing, algunas opciones que tienes son agregar banderas para modificar la forma en que se renderiza, ya que internamente usa [java-2d](/questions/tagged/java-2d), por ejemplo:

```
java -jar ./mi_programa.jar -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
```

esta línea si estás en windows lo guardas con la extensión `.bat` y guardas ese archivo junto a tu jar, esta será la forma en que el cliente puede correr tu aplicación con doble click.

[Lista completa de las banderas de renderización](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/2d/flags.html).

Comment: Funciona!, muchas gracias.