# elementos de ventanas desaparecen

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, ventana, jdialog

A medida que le paso el mouse encima peor se pone la ventana, si lo cierro el problema sigue con las demás ventanas, esto ocurre solo algunas veces, luego de oprimir en guardar o tambien en el boton cancelar, pero no es regla, a veces pasa con otras acciones, si oprimo en el netbeans en clean and build project, el problema desaparece por algunos dias, tambien esto ocurre con el jar, un amigo me dijo que tuvo el mismo problema y se debía a que tenia elementos sobrepuestos, pero en mi caso no tengo nada encima de otro elemento, llevo años con este problema, si alguien tiene alguna idea de lo que está pasando

[image: A medida que le paso el mouse encima peor se pone la ventana]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Componentes del Formulario se desconfiguran - NetBeans](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/403135/componentes-del-formulario-se-desconfiguran-netbeans)

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias!!